# Erro DispatcherTimer C# (Universal app win 10)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Sou novato em programação e consegui fazer esse código com ajuda, só que esta ocorrendo um erro. segue imagem.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private MySqlConnection _connection;

    DispatcherTimer mytimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    int currentcout = 0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        mytimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
        mytimer.Tick += new EventHandler(mytimer_Tick);
    }

    private void mytimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Continua ocorrendo erro, mesmo com as alterações passadas pelo colega anteriormente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja: [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas - Postar código como imagem](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/28595)

Comment: No lugar de imagens poste o código da classe, depois você informa que erro está acontecendo.

Comment: coloquei o codigo, como informado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
private readonly DispatcherTimer _mytimer = new DispatcherTimer();
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _mytimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5, 0);
    _mytimer.Tick += Mytimer_Tick;
    _mytimer.Start();
}

private void Mytimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"executado: {DateTime.Now}");
}
```

Obs: Deve-se utilizar o método `_mytimer.Start();` para iniciar o `Timer`